# Best way to compute max mask of sse var

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, sse

(I'm only interested in the 1st 3 components)

For example:
`[ 1 2 3 ? ]` should produce `[ 0 0 -1 ? ]`

Also, it's important to have only one "bit" set so that:
`[ 1 2 2 ? ]` should not produce `[ 0 -1 -1 ? ]`
but rather
`[ 0 -1 0 ? ]` or `[ 0 0 -1 ? ]` (doesn't matter which one)

The later (bad) solution is possible for example by extracting the horizontal max and comparing to the original:

```
__m128 abcd; // input
__m128 ccac           = _mm_shuffle_ps(abcd, abcd, 0x8A);
__m128 abcd_ccac      = _mm_max_ps(abcd, ccac);
__m128 babb           = _mm_shuffle_ps(abcd, abcd, 0x51);
__m128 abcd_ccac_babb = _mm_max_ps(abcd_ccac, babb);
__m128 mask           = _mm_cmpeq_ps(abcd, abcd_ccac_babb);
```

Perhaps some bitwise operations to get rid of duplicate set bits?

**Update:**

Follow up, I've made another (bad) solution.
The key is to compare each component to another, avoiding equality equations (not having `a >= b` and `b >= a` in another place).

`a > b & a >= c`
`b > c & b >= a`
`c > a & c >= b`

to yield:

`([ a b c ? ] > [ b c a ? ]) & ([ a b c ? ] >= [ c a b ? ])`

and in code:

```
__m128 abcd; // input
__m128 bcad = _mm_shuffle_ps(abcd, abcd, 0xC9);
__m128 gt   = _mm_cmpgt_ps(abcd, bcad);
__m128 cabd = _mm_shuffle_ps(abcd, abcd, 0xD2);
__m128 ge   = _mm_cmpge_ps(abcd, cabd);
__m128 mask = _mm_and_ps(gt, ge);
```

It fails in the case of `[ x x x ? ]` (produces `[ 0 0 0 ? ]`).

Getting close :-)

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I'm now using the following solution:

```
__m128  abcd; // input
__m128  bcad = _mm_shuffle_ps(abcd, abcd, 0xC9);
__m128  gt   = _mm_cmpgt_ps(abcd, bcad);
__m128  cabd = _mm_shuffle_ps(abcd, abcd, 0xD2);
__m128  ge   = _mm_cmpge_ps(abcd, cabd);
__m128  and  = _mm_and_ps(gt, ge);
__m128i bits = _mm_setr_epi32(_mm_movemask_ps(and), -1, -1, -1);
__m128i dirt = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(bits, _mm_setzero_si128());
__m128i mask = _mm_or_si128(dirt, _mm_castps_si128(and));
```

Comment: I can't see any efficient or elegant way of doing this right now - all I can come up with so far is to extract the 4 MS bits from `mask` using `_mm_movemask_ps` and then process this to get a unique single bit value, which you can then convert back to a mask vector if needed.

Comment: Do you have to do this sequential or can you do this independently for example if you have a 2D array like {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},...} can you find the max for {1,2,3} and {4,5,6} independently?  If you can do this independently for different sets of numbers then it's going to be more efficient with SIMD.

Comment: @PaulR `_mm_movemask_ps` as an approach for bitwise operations is very welcomed.

Comment: @Zboson unfortunately i'm limited to have the whole operation on the same SIMD variable, regardless the inefficiency of that comparing to vertical operations

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this, but I trust it will get you -1 in only the first (highest-order) occurrence of the maximum value:

```
__m128 abcd; // input
__m128 ccac = _mm_shuffle_ps( abcd,abcd,0x8A );
__m128 abcd_ccac = _mm_max_ps( abcd,ccac );
__m128 babb = _mm_shuffle_ps( abcd,abcd,0x51 );
__m128 abcd_ccac_babb = _mm_max_ps( abcd_ccac,babb );
__m128 mask = _mm_cmpeq_ps( abcd,abcd_ccac_babb );

// set the '?' position in mask to zero
mask = _mm_blend_ps( mask,_mm_setzero_ps(),0x08 );
// shift mask left 32 bits shifting in zeros
__m128 maskSrl32 = _mm_shuffle_ps( mask,mask,_MM_SHUFFLE( 3,1,0,3 ) );
// shift mask left 64 bits shifting in zeros
__m128 maskSrl64 = _mm_shuffle_ps( mask,mask,_MM_SHUFFLE( 3,0,3,3 ) );
// andnot the shifted masks with mask
// in doing so, the higher order set bits will suppress any set bits which follow
mask = _mm_andnot_ps( maskSrl32,mask );
mask = _mm_andnot_ps( maskSrl64,mask );
// select -1 using the final mask
__m128 result = _mm_and_ps( mask,_mm_set1_ps( -1.0f ) );
```

Reverse the shifting direction to yield -1 in the lowest-order max position instead.

Comment: This fails for the common example: `[ 4, 3, 2 x ]` (produces `[ 0 0 0 x ]`).
(what is this '?' position purpose?)

Comment: @GolanRoss I fixed the routine and tested it. It should work fine now (I originally got the order of the vector elements mixed up in my head). The '?' position is the element that you said you're not interested in. It needs to be cleared to facilitate shifting of the elements.

Comment: Interesting choice of `blend_ps` to selectively zero, instead of `and_ps` with a mask.  It's more efficient than I though: single uop, and can run on 2 or 3 ports on Intel SnB / Haswell (respectively).  However, you could get the zeroing for free with `_mm_bslli_si128(src, byte_count)` instead of `shuffle_ps`  (You'll have to cast to `__m128i`.  I don't think there's extra latency (bypass delay) for forwarding a result from `cmpeq_ps` to an integer shuffle instead of FP shuffle.  (`pslldq` runs on the shuffle unit, same as `shufps`).

Comment: If you're using an integer shuffle anyway, you can and should stay in the integer domain for the `andnot` operations, too.  Using a final `and_ps` will make sure there's no bypass delay when using the result in an FP ALU operation (like add or multiply).